# I need formula with VLOOKUP and If Then

Tags: excel

I need column L to contain formula where there is a VLOOKUP looking for a match in K to names in H
If K is blank, result is blank, but if K is not blank, L should be blank if there is a match found in H but the word COPY if there is not a match

[image]

Comment: Post your formula to post. Also post you desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(K2,H2:H7,1,FALSE)),"COPY","Blank")
```

Can look up for more details in this page
https://www.exceltip.com/tips/how-to-use-if-isna-and-vlookup-function-in-excel.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).